# Differential equation about Complex functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, complex-integration

$z\in \mathbb{C}$

$f(z)$ : meromorphic function in a connected domain

I cannot solve this differential equation.

\begin{equation}
f'(z)=f(z)^2 \cdots \ast
\end{equation}

My mathematic book says "Integrate the equation $\ast$ for $f$.

But I cannot know what I should do.

If I integrate $\ast$ for $f$,

\begin{equation}
f(z)=\int f(z)^2 dz
\end{equation}

I cannot proceed from this.

And I tried by another way.

I represent $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n z^n$, and the equation $\ast$ is
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)c_{n+1} z^n
=\left(
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n z^n \right)^2
\end{equation}
But this approach doesn't seem to work.

So I want to solve by integrating the equation $\ast$ for $f$, as my book says.

What should I do?

Comment: What is $(1/f)'$?

Comment: Note that "integrate" is just a word used to mean "solve a differential equation" sometimes. Don't get too hung up on the terminology. Also computing out Conrad's hint should suggest to you the answer.

Comment: @Conrad $(1/f)'=-1.$ Thus $1/f=-z+C, f=1/(-z+C)$. Is this idea correct?

Comment: Yes this is correct

Answer (score 1):

One might proceed as follows: in any region where

$f(z) \ne 0, \; \; (1) \tag 1$

we have

$\left (\dfrac{1}{f(z)} \right )' = (f^{-1}(z))' = -f^{-2}(z)f'(z) = -\dfrac{f'(z)}{f^2(z)} 
;  \; \; (2) \tag 2$

now if

$f'(z) = f^2(z), \tag 3$

then

$\dfrac{f'(z)}{f^2(z)} = 1, \tag 4$

so in accord with (2),

$\left (\dfrac{1}{f(z)} \right )' = -1; \tag 5$

we may integrate this along a path 'twixt $z_0$ and $z$:

$\dfrac{1}{f(z)} - \dfrac{1}{f(z_0)} = \displaystyle \int_{z_0}^z \left (\dfrac{1}{f(w)} \right )'\; dw = \int_{z_0}^z (-1)\; dw = z_0 - z; \tag 6$

we now solve for $f(z)$ algebraically:

$\dfrac{1}{f(z)} = z_0 - z + \dfrac{1}{f(z_0)} = \dfrac{f(z_0)(z_0 - z) + 1}{f(z_0)}, \tag 7$

or

$f(z) = \dfrac{f(z_0)}{f(z_0)(z_0 - z) + 1} = f(z_0)(f(z_0)(z_0 - z) + 1)^{-1}, \tag 8$

which may easily be checked by direct differentiation; from (8),

$f'(z) = -f(z_0)(f(z_0)(z_0 - z) + 1)^{-2}(-f(z_0)) = f^2(z_0)(f(z_0)(z_0 - z) + 1)^{-2} = f^2(z), \tag 9$

which is (3).  We also see that (8) yields

$f(z_0) = f(z_0)(f(z_0)(z_0 - z_0) + 1)^{-1} = f(z_0)(1^{-1}) = f(z_0), \tag{10}$

which demonstrates that $f(z)$ satisfies the appropriate boundary/initial condition at $z_0$.

It is perhaps worth observing that the hypothesis (1) is satisfied by (8) for all $z \in \Bbb C$ as long as $f(z_0) \ne 0$, that is, the solution is non-trivial.